# Frameworks not found for CocoaPods with Xcode 6.3.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dependencies, cocoapods

My `Podfile` is as follows:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'podtest' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
end
```

And I definitely am opening up the Xcworkspace file, not the xcodeproj file. It throws a `Mach-O` linker error in even the simplest project I could possibly make, with the -F flag.

Comment: Does it work when you put   pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1' outside target?

Comment: @SahilKapoor when I do that, it shows Pods.framework as missing